Integrating Java and C# APIs for User Authentication and Authorization in Swagger
I have two APIs, one written in Java and the other in C#. The Java API handles user management, authentication, and authorization, while the C# API focuses on functionalities related to ideas and topics. The C# API relies on the Java API for user authentication and authorization. Each user should only be able to edit or delete their own ideas or topics, while everyone can view them.
I'm currently working on implementing the APIs using Swagger, but I'm struggling to integrate and identify the tokens created by the Java API for user authentication. Additionally, I'm unsure how to properly handle authorization to restrict actions in the C# API based on user permissions.
I need guidance on how to effectively integrate the Java and C# APIs in Swagger, particularly regarding user authentication and authorization. Specifically, I'm seeking advice on how to utilize and identify tokens generated by the Java API within the Swagger documentation and how to implement proper authorization mechanisms to control user actions in the C# API. Any insights or examples on the correct approach to achieve this integration and ensure secure access to resources would be greatly appreciated.
